# Reporting Services Textbox "Line Break"

Tags: ssrs-2008, line-breaks

I am bringing data over from Oracle into SSRS. One dataset pulls in a a string of names and initials divided by a semi colon. :

EX: Ratliff, J D;Schlue, R S

I would like to insert a line break after each semicolon and bold the very last line to display as follows:

Ratliff, J D;

**Schlue, R S**

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: It is a good idea as well to keep a list of VB character replacements handy in a nearby knowledge base. You never know when you are going to need them.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap that name field in an expression that simply replaces the ";" character with a line break character.  That should give you the desired behavior.

Gerry Lee, SQL Server Reporting Services

Comment: I have tried that... I was setting the column to a specified width and adding extra spaces. Yours is more reliable, thank you.